# how to limit the page number?

Tags: php, html, pagination

My code show all number of page on one page.I want to limit the number of page?

My code is

```
$start_date = $_REQUEST['date1'];
$end_date = $_REQUEST['date2'];

$condition="1=1";
if ($start_date!="")
    $condition.=" AND event_date>='".date( "Y-m-d", strtotime($start_date))."'";
if ($end_date!="")
    $condition.=" AND event_date<='".date( "Y-m-d", strtotime($end_date))."'";
$start_date = date( "Y-m-d", strtotime($start_date));
$end_date = date( "Y-m-d", strtotime($end_date));

$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
if (!$link) 
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
if ($_REQUEST["orderby"]!="") $ord = " ORDER BY ".$_REQUEST["orderby"];
if ($_REQUEST["dir"]!="") $ord .= " ".$_REQUEST["dir"];

mysql_select_db("intern_db", $link);
$page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;

$recordPerPage= '30';
$startPoint = ($page - 1)*$recordPerPage;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) cnt FROM ` admin_crmf_poc_event_history` where   $condition");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$num_rows = $row["cnt"];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ` admin_crmf_poc_event_history` where $condition   $ord LIMIT $startPoint,$recordPerPage");
$totalPages=ceil($num_rows/$recordPerPage);

if ($page > 1) {
    echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='.($page-   1).'&date1='.$_REQUEST["date1"].'&date2='.$_REQUEST["date2"].'">Previous</a>';
}
for ($i = 1; $i < $totalPages; $i++) {
    echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page= '. $i  .'&date1='.$_REQUEST["date1"].'&date2='.$_REQUEST["date2"].'">' . $i . '</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;';
}
if ($page < $totalPages ) {
    echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='. ($page+1).'&date1='.$_REQUEST["date1"].'&date2='.$_REQUEST["date2"].'">Next</a>';
}
echo "<br>";
echo "you are in $page page";
mysql_close($link);
```

I want to show like `previous 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 next`.
When I click next it will show the other 10 pages from 11 to 20 and so on

Comment: A good idea for you will be to use some ready pagination function or class.. There is no need to "Discover America".. 
In your code you don't escape your data and anyone can make sql injection which is not good.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I comment your question, there are `A LOT` of problems inside your code so better will be to use some ready function/class for it :) just search for it ..

How ever I can give you easy way to display what you want..

Replace your FOR loop with that code and it will be fine :)

```
$start = ( floor($page/10) * 10 ) + 1;
for( $i = $start; $i < $totalPages; $i++){
    if( $i >= ($start + 10)){
        break;
    }
    echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page= '. $i  .'&date1='.$_REQUEST["date1"].'&date2='.$_REQUEST["date2"].'">' . $i . '</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;';
}
```

But really  `SECURE YOUR CODE` !!!

> 1st - MYSQL_ functions are deprecated use mysqli or PDO instead..
>
> 2nd - ESCAPE all variables in your queries..
>
> 3rd - Think for using more flexible methods of work (function/objects ..)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Actually I am new to php and mysql. I will follow  your instructions in future. Thank you again, your code works `:)`

Comment: what I should do if I want it in reverse order also??

Answer (score 1):

There are like hundreds of tutorial on how to do this already. Have you tried Googling?

https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=php+mysql+pagination

Here's a few examples:

- http://php.about.com/od/phpwithmysql/ss/php_pagination.htm
- http://www.phpjabbers.com/php--mysql-select-data-and-split-on-pages-php25.html
- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/mysql_paging_php.htm

etc...